# Why C# Encoding.UTF8 different byte decoding to same chars?

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

```
byte[] b1 = new byte[] { 60, 239, 191, 189, 14, 239, 191, 189, 2, 14, 62, 32, 23, 37, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 127, 58, 50, 52, 56, 32, 95, 112, 117, 98, 95, 110, 117, 98, 95, 99, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 112, 112, 32, 58, 111, 110, 82, 101, 99, 101, 105, 118, 101, 84, 97, 112, 78, 111, 116, 105, 102, 121, 68, 97, 116, 97, 13, 10 };
byte[] b2 = new byte[] { 60, 215, 14, 235, 164, 2, 14, 62, 32, 23, 37, 207, 255, 127, 58, 50, 52, 56, 32, 95, 112, 117, 98, 95, 110, 117, 98, 95, 99, 108, 105, 101, 110, 116, 46, 99, 112, 112, 32, 58, 111, 110, 82, 101, 99, 101, 105, 118, 101, 84, 97, 112, 78, 111, 116, 105, 102, 121, 68, 97, 116, 97, 13, 10 };

var s1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b1);
var s2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b2);

var sc1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s1);
var sc2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s2);
```

Surprisingly, `s1 == s2` evaluates to `true`: s1 and s2 now both contain the same string `"<�\u000e�\u0002\u000e> \u0017%��\u007f:248 _pub_nub_client.cpp :onReceiveTapNotifyData\r\n"`, even though the byte sequences are different.

And `sc1 == sc2 == 71` But `b2.Length == 64`

I want to get the number of bytes occupied by the `s2`. The `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(s2)` is 71, which may be inconsistent with b2.Length. So is there any good way to solve this problem?

Comment: Good question. I suspect it's because the byte array contains byte sequences that are invalid in UTF-8 and which get "merged" to the same "�" replacement character, but I'll let the Unicode experts answer this.

Comment: @Heinzi is correct. "�" is U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER, which is used when an invalid sequence is encountered. All invalid sequences convert to the same �. If you want an exception when an invalid sequence is encountered, use the `UTF8Encoding(Boolean, Boolean)` constructor and pass `throwOnInvalidBytes: true`. If you want some other behavior, you can create a custom decoder with a specific Fallback.

Comment: My main intention is to get strings from the file stream and record the location and length of their stream so that I can quickly locate the problem of a particular string in the stream next time. Then I encountered this problem so that I could not analyze the correct byte length of the string in the stream, so is there any good way to solve this problem?

Comment: The real problem is that the file contains illegal UTF-8 sequence. Maybe UTF-8 is not the encoding?

Comment: It seems that you already know the byte lengths (`b1.Length` and `b2.Length`), so no need to recalculate it (much less recalculate it via a lossy round trip conversion).

Comment: So the question turns to 'how to get the occupied byte length from a string containing an illegal UTF-8 sequence'?

Comment: @Jim.Jiang: You can't. That information was lost when the not-UTF-8 byte sequence was parsed as UTF-8. Analogy: Imagine a string-to-integer parser that converts invalid integers to `-1`, e.g. something like (the non-existing) `Int32.ParseOrReturnMinus1`. Now parse `a` and `bbb`. Both result in `-1`, but you can't discover the contents of the original string just by looking at `-1`.

Comment: @Heinzi
My main intention is to read a file such as:

`Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.`

Then I analyze the starting position and length of each line of characters in the file stream.
For example:

`Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (0-16).
Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (17-32).`
I cache the start and end of these two sets of data, and I can quickly navigate to a specified row the next time I need to read it. The problem now is that I can't get the length of the row data correctly. So is there any way to implement this?

Comment: Can't you use similar logic on the byte array instead? It seems to me there is no need to convert to a string based on the problem description.

Comment: Why did you pick `Encoding.UTF8`? The data you have is not UTF-8. Even with proper UTF-8 data, there is no simple relation between the byte count of the input and the "character" count (which can be interpreted in several ways) of the decoded string. There are other encodings for which each byte maps simply to one character. Some of them even have the property (unlike UTF-8) that any input byte sequence is valid.

Comment: @lgor Because I used StreamReader.ReadLine () to get a row of data, then I ran into some strange problems. Maybe I can consider your plan. Sounds like a good suggestion.

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen Because this file is a log, the format stored by the client is UTF8, or may be the data returned by some network requests is in the wrong encoding format.

Comment: You should record the start position and length in bytes instead of characters, since seeking through the stream is done in bytes anyway. Read the `streamReader.BaseStream.Position` before reading a line. That's your start point. Then read it again after reading a line. The difference is the length in bytes.

Comment: @Raymond Chen `StreamReader` uses cached reading, and each read will read 1024 bytes of data, so we have no way to get the actual offset through `streamReader.BaseStream.Position`

Comment: Well then how were you planning to know where to seek back in the stream even if all the characters decoded into UTF8 successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @igor, by getting the byte array, I finally got what I wanted

First we can use `public ValueTuple<long, int>? ReadLinePosition()` to read start position and bytes length, and then we can use `public string? ReadString(long position, int length)` to get the actual value.

I refer to `StreamReader` source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,b5fe1efcec14de32

```
    // This is designed for character input in a particular Encoding, 
    // whereas the Stream class is designed for byte input and output.  
    // 
    [Serializable]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
    public class StreamBytesLineReader
    {
        // Using a 1K byte buffer and a 4K FileStream buffer works out pretty well
        // perf-wise.  On even a 40 MB text file, any perf loss by using a 4K
        // buffer is negated by the win of allocating a smaller byte[], which 
        // saves construction time.  This does break adaptive buffering,
        // but this is slightly faster.
        internal static int DefaultBufferSize
        {
            get
            {
                return 1024 * 4;
            }
        }

        private const int DefaultFileStreamBufferSize = 4096;
        private const int MinBufferSize = 128;

        private Stream stream;
        private Encoding encoding;
        private Decoder decoder;
        private byte[] byteBuffer;
        private byte[] _preamble;   // Encoding's preamble, which identifies this encoding.
        // Record the number of valid bytes in the byteBuffer, for a few checks.
        private int byteLen;
        // This is used only for preamble detection
        private int bytePos;

        // We will support looking for byte order marks in the stream and trying
        // to decide what the encoding might be from the byte order marks, IF they
        // exist.  But that's all we'll do.  
        private bool _detectEncoding;

        // Whether we must still check for the encoding's given preamble at the
        // beginning of this file.
        private bool _checkPreamble;

        // The intent of this field is to leave open the underlying stream when 
        // disposing of this LineStreamReader1.  A name like _leaveOpen is better, 
        // but this type is serializable, and this field's name was _closable.
        private bool _closable;  // Whether to close the underlying stream.

        internal void InternalBlockCopy(Array src, int srcOffsetBytes, Array dst, int dstOffsetBytes, int byteCount)
        {
            Array.Copy(src, srcOffsetBytes, dst, dstOffsetBytes, byteCount);
        }

        public long Position => stream.Position - byteLen + bytePos;

        public StreamBytesLineReader(Stream stream)
            : this(stream, true)
        {
        }

        public StreamBytesLineReader(Stream stream, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks)
            : this(stream, Encoding.UTF8, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, DefaultBufferSize, false)
        {
        }
        public StreamBytesLineReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
            : this(stream, encoding, true, DefaultBufferSize, false)
        {
        }

#nullable disable
        public StreamBytesLineReader(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSize, bool leaveOpen)
#nullable enable
        {
            if (stream == null || encoding == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException((stream == null ? "stream" : "encoding"));
            if (!stream.CanRead)
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument_StreamNotReadable");
            if (bufferSize <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bufferSize", "ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedPosNum");
            Contract.EndContractBlock();

            Init(stream, encoding, detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, bufferSize, leaveOpen);
        }

        private void Init(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, bool detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, int bufferSize, bool leaveOpen)
        {
            this.stream = stream;
            this.encoding = encoding;
            decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
            if (bufferSize < MinBufferSize) bufferSize = MinBufferSize;
            byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            byteLen = 0;
            bytePos = 0;
            _detectEncoding = detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks;
            _preamble = encoding.GetPreamble();
            _checkPreamble = (_preamble.Length > 0);
            _closable = !leaveOpen;
            ResetReadLinePosition();
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            // Dispose of our resources if this LineStreamReader1 is closable.
            // Note that Console.In should be left open.
            try
            {
                // Note that Stream.Close() can potentially throw here. So we need to 
                // ensure cleaning up internal resources, inside the finally block.  
                if (!LeaveOpen && disposing && (stream != null))
                    stream.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!LeaveOpen && (stream != null))
                {
#nullable disable
                    stream = null;
                    encoding = null;
                    decoder = null;
                    byteBuffer = null;
#nullable enable
                }
            }
        }

        private Func<ValueTuple<long, int>?> ReadLinePositionFunc { get; set; }

        public virtual Encoding CurrentEncoding
        {
            get { return encoding; }
        }

        public virtual Stream BaseStream
        {
            get { return stream; }
        }

        internal bool LeaveOpen
        {
            get { return !_closable; }
        }

        // Trims n bytes from the front of the buffer.
        private void CompressBuffer(int n)
        {
            Contract.Assert(byteLen >= n, "CompressBuffer was called with a number of bytes greater than the current buffer length.  Are two threads using this LineStreamReader1 at the same time?");
            InternalBlockCopy(byteBuffer, n, byteBuffer, 0, byteLen - n);
            byteLen -= n;
        }

        private void DetectEncoding()
        {
            if (byteLen < 2)
                return;
            _detectEncoding = false;
            bool changedEncoding = false;
            if (byteBuffer[0] == 0xFE && byteBuffer[1] == 0xFF)
            {
                // Big Endian Unicode

                encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(true, true);
                CompressBuffer(2);
                changedEncoding = true;
            }

            else if (byteBuffer[0] == 0xFF && byteBuffer[1] == 0xFE)
            {
                // Little Endian Unicode, or possibly little endian UTF32
                if (byteLen < 4 || byteBuffer[2] != 0 || byteBuffer[3] != 0)
                {
                    encoding = new UnicodeEncoding(false, true);
                    CompressBuffer(2);
                    changedEncoding = true;
                }
            }

            else if (byteLen >= 3 && byteBuffer[0] == 0xEF && byteBuffer[1] == 0xBB && byteBuffer[2] == 0xBF)
            {
                // UTF-8
                encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                CompressBuffer(3);
                changedEncoding = true;
            }
            else if (byteLen == 2)
                _detectEncoding = true;
            // Note: in the future, if we change this algorithm significantly,
            // we can support checking for the preamble of the given encoding.

            if (changedEncoding)
            {
                decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
                ResetReadLinePosition();
            }
        }

        private void ResetReadLinePosition()
        {
            if (encoding.EncodingName == "Unicode (Big-Endian)")
            {
                ReadLinePositionFunc = ReadLinePositionUnicodeBE;
            }
            else if (encoding.EncodingName == "Unicode")
            {
                ReadLinePositionFunc = ReadLinePositionUnicode;
            }
            else
            {
                ReadLinePositionFunc = ReadLinePositionUTF8;
            }
        }

        // DiscardBufferedData tells LineStreamReader1 to throw away its internal
        // buffer contents.  This is useful if the user needs to seek on the
        // underlying stream to a known location then wants the LineStreamReader1
        // to start reading from this new point.  This method should be called
        // very sparingly, if ever, since it can lead to very poor performance.
        // However, it may be the only way of handling some scenarios where 
        // users need to re-read the contents of a LineStreamReader1 a second time.
        public void DiscardBufferedData()
        {
            _checkPreamble = true;
            byteLen = 0;
            // in general we'd like to have an invariant that encoding isn't null. However,
            // for startup improvements for NullStreamReader, we want to delay load encoding. 
            if (encoding != null)
            {
                decoder = encoding.GetDecoder();
            }
        }

        // Trims the preamble bytes from the byteBuffer. This routine can be called multiple times
        // and we will buffer the bytes read until the preamble is matched or we determine that
        // there is no match. If there is no match, every byte read previously will be available 
        // for further consumption. If there is a match, we will compress the buffer for the 
        // leading preamble bytes
        private bool IsPreamble()
        {
            if (!_checkPreamble)
                return _checkPreamble;

            Contract.Assert(bytePos <= _preamble.Length, "_compressPreamble was called with the current bytePos greater than the preamble buffer length.  Are two threads using this LineStreamReader1 at the same time?");
            int len = (byteLen >= (_preamble.Length)) ? (_preamble.Length - bytePos) : (byteLen - bytePos);

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++, bytePos++)
            {
                if (byteBuffer[bytePos] != _preamble[bytePos])
                {
                    bytePos = 0;
                    _checkPreamble = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            Contract.Assert(bytePos <= _preamble.Length, "possible bug in _compressPreamble.  Are two threads using this LineStreamReader1 at the same time?");

            if (_checkPreamble)
            {
                if (bytePos == _preamble.Length)
                {
                    // We have a match
                    CompressBuffer(_preamble.Length);
                    bytePos = 0;
                    _checkPreamble = false;
                    _detectEncoding = false;
                }
            }

            return _checkPreamble;
        }

        internal virtual int ReadBuffer()
        {
            bytePos = 0;
            if (!_checkPreamble)
                byteLen = 0;
            do
            {
                if (_checkPreamble)
                {
                    //Contract.Assert(bytePos <= _preamble.Length, "possible bug in _compressPreamble.  Are two threads using this LineStreamReader1 at the same time?");
                    int len = stream.Read(byteBuffer, bytePos, byteBuffer.Length - bytePos);
                    //Contract.Assert(len >= 0, "Stream.Read returned a negative number!  This is a bug in your stream class.");

                    if (len == 0)
                    {
                        // EOF but we might have buffered bytes from previous 
                        // attempt to detect preamble that needs to be decoded now
                        if (byteLen > 0)
                        {
                            // Need to zero out the byteLen after we consume these bytes so that we don't keep infinitely hitting this code path
                            bytePos = byteLen = 0;
                        }

                        return byteLen;
                    }

                    byteLen += len;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Contract.Assert(bytePos == 0, "bytePos can be non zero only when we are trying to _checkPreamble.  Are two threads using this LineStreamReader1 at the same time?");
                    byteLen = stream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length);
                    //Contract.Assert(byteLen >= 0, "Stream.Read returned a negative number!  This is a bug in your stream class.");

                    if (byteLen == 0)  // We're at EOF
                        return byteLen;
                }

                // Check for preamble before detect encoding. This is not to override the
                // user suppplied Encoding for the one we implicitly detect. The user could
                // customize the encoding which we will loose, such as ThrowOnError on UTF8
                if (IsPreamble())
                    continue;

                // If we're supposed to detect the encoding and haven't done so yet,
                // do it.  Note this may need to be called more than once.
                if (_detectEncoding && byteLen >= 2)
                    DetectEncoding();

            } while (byteLen == 0);
            //Console.WriteLine("ReadBuffer called.  chars: "+charLen);
            return byteLen;
        }

        // Reads a line. A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by
        // a carriage return ('\r'), a line feed ('\n'), or a carriage return
        // immediately followed by a line feed. The resulting string does not
        // contain the terminating carriage return and/or line feed. The returned
        // value is null if the end of the input stream has been reached.
        //
        public ValueTuple<long, int>? ReadLinePosition()
        {
            return ReadLinePositionFunc.Invoke();
        }
        private ValueTuple<long, int>? ReadLinePositionUnicodeBE()
        {
            if (stream == null)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(null, "ObjectDisposed_ReaderClosed");

            if (bytePos == byteLen)
            {
#nullable disable
                if (ReadBuffer() == 0) return null;
#nullable enable
            }

            long start = Position;
            do
            {
                int i = bytePos;
                do
                {
                    byte b = byteBuffer[i];
                    if (b == 0x0)
                    {
                        bytePos = i + 1;
                        if ((bytePos < byteLen || ReadBuffer() > 0) && (byteBuffer[bytePos] == 0xD || byteBuffer[bytePos] == 0XA))
                        {
                            bytePos++;
                            if ((bytePos < byteLen || ReadBuffer() > 0) && byteBuffer[bytePos] == 0x0)
                            {
                                if ((++bytePos < byteLen || ReadBuffer() > 0) && byteBuffer[bytePos] == 0xA)
                                {
                                    bytePos++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    bytePos--;
                                }
                            }
                            return new ValueTuple<long, int>(start, (int)(Position - start));
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                } while (i < byteLen);
            } while (ReadBuffer() > 0);
            return new ValueTuple<long, int>(start, (int)(Position - start));
        }
        private ValueTuple<long, int>? ReadLinePositionUnicode()
        {
            if (stream == null)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(null, "ObjectDisposed_ReaderClosed");

            if (bytePos == byteLen)
            {
#nullable disable
                if (ReadBuffer() == 0) return null;
#nullable enable
            }

            long start = Position;
            do
            {
                int i = bytePos;
                do
                {
                    byte b = byteBuffer[i];
                    if (b == 0xD || b == 0XA)
                    {
                        bytePos = i + 1;
                        if ((bytePos < byteLen || ReadBuffer() > 0) && byteBuffer[bytePos] == 0x0)
                        {
                            bytePos++;
                            if (b == 0xD && (bytePos < byteLen || ReadBuffer() > 0) && byteBuffer[bytePos] == 0xA)
                            {
                                if ((++bytePos < byteLen || ReadBuffer() > 0) && byteBuffer[bytePos] == 0x0)
                                {
                                    bytePos++;
                                }
                            }
                            return new ValueTuple<long, int>(start, (int)(Position - start));
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                } while (i < byteLen);
            } while (ReadBuffer() > 0);
            return new ValueTuple<long, int>(start, (int)(Position - start));
        }
        private ValueTuple<long, int>? ReadLinePositionUTF8()
        {
            if (stream == null)
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(null, "ObjectDisposed_ReaderClosed");

            if (bytePos == byteLen)
            {
#nullable disable
                if (ReadBuffer() == 0) return null;
#nullable enable
            }

            long start = Position;
            do
            {
                int i = bytePos;
                do
                {
                    byte b = byteBuffer[i];
                    if (b == 0xD || b == 0XA)
                    {
                        bytePos = i + 1;
                        if (b == 0xD && (bytePos < byteLen || ReadBuffer() > 0) && byteBuffer[bytePos] == 0XA)
                        {
                            bytePos++;
                        }
                        return new ValueTuple<long, int>(start, (int)(Position - start));
                    }
                    i++;
                } while (i < byteLen);
            } while (ReadBuffer() > 0);
            return new ValueTuple<long, int>(start, (int)(Position - start));
        }

        public string? ReadString(long position, int length)
        {
            if (length <= 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (position + length > stream.Length)
            {
                return null;
            }
            byte[] bBuffer = new byte[length];
            var lastPosition = stream.Position;
            stream.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            int bLen = stream.Read(bBuffer, 0, length);
            stream.Seek(lastPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var result = encoding.GetString(bBuffer, 0, bLen);
            return result;
        }

        public string? ReadString(ValueTuple<long, int>? linePosition)
        {
            if (linePosition == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return ReadString(linePosition.Value.Item1, linePosition.Value.Item2);
        }
    }
```